# How to precache SVG images with flutter_svg version 2.0 and above?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I have recently updated my flutter_svg to version 2.0.5, and I'm having a bit of a problem with precaching SVG images, which I didn't have with the previous version. I used to precache my SVG images using the `precachePicture` function and the `SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderOutsideViewBoxBuilder` method like this:

```
precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderOutsideViewBoxBuilder,
    "assets/images/file.svg"), context);
```

However, with the recent updates, it seems that both `precachePicture` and `SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderOutsideViewBoxBuilder` are no longer available. I have tried to find a replacement or a similar function in the updated version, but so far I have had no luck.

Does anyone have any advice on how to precache SVG images in the updated flutter_svg package? Is there a new function or method to use?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/841#issuecomment-1416160435)

Answer (score 2):

thanks to the referred github issue from @VictorEronmosele.
My problem was solved with

```
var loader = SvgAssetLoader(svgPath);
  await svg.cache
      .putIfAbsent(loader.cacheKey(null), () => loader.loadBytes(null));
```